# ImGuiConfigFlags_DockingEnable not found

Tags: c++, opengl, imgui

I'm trying to implement ImGui in my opengl app, but, for some reasons, the flag:

ImGuiConfigFlags_DockingEnable

is not found. I even tried to go in the files and I didn't find the  ImGuiConfigFlags_DockingEnable flag in ImGuiConfigFlags_ enum. Any idea?

PS: I included these files:
[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkVwn.jpg)

Comment: Which branch/SHA1 are you using from the ImGui repo?  The 'open' status of [issue 2109](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/2109) suggests that the docking feature hasn't made it to `master` yet.

Comment: Yes, it's because that i used the master branch. I have to use the docking branch. Thx

Answer (score 2):

I might be too late, but it seems like you are using master branch of imgui and this flag is in docking branch